# Angular mdb-select option checkbox disable

Tags: javascript, angular, mdbootstrap

I want to disable the checkbox option for select

```
<mdb-select [options]="optionsList" type="multi_checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selected" placeholder="Choose your option" label="Example label"></mdb-select>
```

```
public selected = [];
public optionsList = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Option 1', disabled: false },
    { id: 2, label: 'Option 2', disabled: false } ,
    { id: 3, label: 'Disabled option', disabled: false } ,
  ];

 ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.updateDisabledState(); // nothing happens here
      this.optionsList = [...this.optionsList] // array reference change, Angular will trigger change detection for options input
    }, 3000);
  }

  updateDisabledState() {
    this.optionsSelect.forEach(option => {
      option.disabled = true;
    })
  }
```

Just by adding `disabled: true` in the array didn't work, hence tried this way but this too failed to disable the checkbox

Approach: Angular only checks if an array reference has changed. If you add new option or update parameter of existing option, the change detection won't be triggered.

Comment: Which MDB Angular and Angular versions do you use? I think the approach is correct, but there are some errors in the code you provided. In the `updateDisableState` method you use `optionsSelect` array instead of `optionsList` (which is used as a reference for the `[options]` input). You also need to add `[multiple]="true"` input to the `mdb-select` component to use multiple mode. I'm not sure if it's only a typo in the sample code or an actual bug in your application.